# OpenSolaris user permissions and problems

Tags: opensolaris, users, groups, chown

I'm trying to achieve the following in OpenSolaris to setup permissions on the ZFS volumes (shared using CIFS).

There are some users who should belong to the sysusers group, they have access to everything and anything in the /tank/storage ZFS volume. In addition there are the following groups:

devs  - Developers
media - Media users who can only access certain folders
accnt - Accountants who can only touch their files

I thought maybe of creating the groups above, then the sysusers group and adding all the groups above to the sysusers group - which in turn will add all the users in sysgroup to have global access.

Is this suitable? The other problem is that I tried to do this:

```
# pfexec groupadd media
# pfexec chown media:media /tank/media/assets
```

but I get the following:

```
# pfexec chown media:media /tank/media/assets
chown: `media:media': invalid user
```

I'm confused, should I not see 'media' considering I just created it? I tried associating staff to it but then it says:

```
chown: `staff': invalid user
```

I'm trying to follow the directions [here](http://breden.org.uk/2009/05/10/home-fileserver-zfs-file-systems/) in particular the part about 'Create the media file systems for music, photos and video'. I get stuck at 'chown media:media /tank/media/music'.

I'm so confused :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chown` takes `<user>:<group>` so your trying to change ownership to user: media, group: media, but you don't have a user media, only a group.

Comment: +1 I don't think you have a user media

Comment: ah that makes perfect sense. Can I just make the user portion me and anyone in group can modify it?

Comment: Yes, user can be anyone.  I would strongly suggest doing some reading, not only on that article but on opensolaris.org on ACL's.  Default posix ACLs are usually 0755.  It sounds like you want them to be 775 or 770.  You can do a chmod initially, but that won't take care of newly created files. That is what ACLs do for you.  You could also tell (I think) the CIFS server to make default permissions on a share's newly created files 775.